# It is not clear to me if the disjoint union of a $d_{1}$-manifold and a $d_{2}$-manifold is still a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

While it is clear that a disjoint union of two $d$-manifolds is a $d$-manifold, it is not clear to me if the disjoint union of a $d_{1}$-manifold and a $d_{2}$-manifold is still a manifold and if yes under some conditions then what is its dimension?

Answer (score 3):

This is true if and only if $d_1=d_2$.  The definition of a manifold mentions only one dimension, which must be consistent across all charts.

I suppose that in order to truly believe this you must also believe in Invariance of Domain.

Comment: It depends on what you want to take [as your definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2273320/274352).

Comment: If they are not just topological manifolds but smooth manifolds, what will be the conclusion?

Comment: The same, since invariance of domain applies to homeomorphism types, not just diffeo types.